# Python assignment operator associativity

Tags: python, operators

Consider the following Python3 program:

```
a = [0, 0]  
i = 0  
a[i] = i = 1  
print(a, i)  

a = [0, 0]  
i = 0  
i = a[i] = 1  
print(a, i)
```

I expected the output to be:

```
[0, 1] 1
[1, 0] 1
```

But instead I got:

```
[1, 0] 1
[0, 1] 1
```

My question is: is there anything in the Python language specification about associativity of the assignment operator, or is the behavior for the above example undefined?

All I was able to find is that expressions are evaluated form left to right, except that r-value is evaluated first in case of assignment, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Interestingly, your example is very similar to the example at the [end of the section](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short answer:** the code is well defined; the order is left-to-right.

**Long answer:**

First of all, let's get the terminology right. Unlike in some other languages, assignment in Python is a *statement*, not an *operator*. This means that you can't use assignment as part of another expression: for example `i = (j = 0)` is not valid Python code.

The assignment statement is defined to explicitly permit multiple assignment targets (in your example, these are `i` and `a[i]`). Each target can be a list, but let's leave that aside.

Where there are multiple assignment targets, the value is assigned from left to right. To quote the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that
>   this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter
>   yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of
>   the target lists, **from left to right**.

Answer (score 9):

Just to make it clear, since I struggled myself to understand this. The statement:

```
a = b = c = E
```

is equivalent to

```
tmp = E  # expression E evaluated once
a = tmp
b = tmp
c = tmp
```